# What is this black bug, how to control?

Tags: identification, flowers, containers

I am not aware what the flower name is but they flower all around the year.
I am attaching a picture here, please help me identify the black crawling bug on the flowers and how can I control them.

[image: crawling black bug on the flowers]

They were not there a day before, I don't know how in a matter of day an entire colony has got created.I have washed them off today through a jet spray of water.

The plant is also infected with aphid population :(
The average day temperature here right now in about 25 degree centigrade.
The plant gets direct sunlight for about 4-5 hours.

Please help, everyday I end up finding a new kind of bug in one plant or another :(
Are potted plants more prone to pests?

Comment: where do you live / where is this plant kept year-round?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The black bugs are the larvae of ladybugs.  They are there to eat the aphids. As larvae or adults ladybugs are efficient beneficial predators.  There is no need to wash them away they are working for you!

I wonder if you have other plants that have aphids.  Some adults have wings and fly to new hosts.  Check your other plants for aphids.  As they are soft skinned they can be easily controlled by a solution of 5 ml of dish soap in one liter of water applied three times with a hand sprayer at five to seven day intervals.

Comment: Thanks for quick turn-around, I thought so that they might be good bugs too, so saved a few in a small container with few leaves, I have aphids on 'hibiscus' and 'Moon Beam'...I wash them regularly with jet spray  and soap solution but they keep coming back :( Its good I have ladybugs now

Answer (score 2):

The ladybirds and their larvae will do the work for you in controlling aphids, now that you have a food source for them. They are a welcome site in my garden but saw very few last year.